# Are there any journal that does not accept Scientific Workplace tex files

Tags: scientific-workplace

Scientific Workplace is a LaTeX-based word processor. The pro is that it is much easier to type in math symbols and virtually is WYSIWYG. The con is that it does not support some of important LaTeX packages like Tikz.

Tex files generated by SW are somewhat different from LaTeX files and may need conversion. So I wonder if there are journals that do not accept SW tex files for submission.

Comment: Do you really want to be dependent on the SW and choosing the journals on that decision? You're restricting yourself too much, most likely. Learning LaTeX with its commands is not about learning Quantum Field Theory ;-). I think that you learn nothing about LaTeX using  those WYSIWYG interface editors

Comment: I know latex of course. Because I have some long papers created by SW, conversion may be time consuming. I am not sure if there are programs to convert them automatically. So I am asking if there are journals that do not accept SW files

Comment: If a journal provides a custom class file for authors, it's likely that they won't accept SW produced code unless you can get it to exactly match their requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This answer applies to v5.5 (I haven't used 6.0). If you save your file as a Portable LaTeX file, it is straight LaTeX, so you shouldn't have any problem with publishers. I've sent dozens of TeX files to mathematics publishers and the arXiv without problem. You can use Tikz with SWP, but you have to enter the code as code, and you should use a standard TeX system like MiKTeX rather than the built in one.