# How to integrate Tikz code in SW?

Tags: tikz-pgf, scientific-workplace

I'd like to know how to insert Tikz code in Scientific Workplace tex file. Since SW doesn't support Tikz directly, now I just create Tikz code in another tex editor and export as pdf. Then I convert pdf to images, and import images into SW.

Comment: Sorry, I have problems understanding your question. You are working with something that does not support Ti*k*Z directly, and you tell us your workaround. So what is your question?

Comment: Someone says that he knows how to do it. Read https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413572/are-there-any-journal-that-does-not-accept-scientific-workplace-tex-files. So I am waiting for answer.

Comment: You should link to your earlier question in this one. Note that the answer there already gives you a workaround, since you could export to regular `.tex` and then add in Ti*k*Z.

Comment: I want to remain in SW because I like SW interface and I don't have many figures.

Comment: Related :) https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413309

Comment: Please don't clutter the site by asking duplicate questions. You can always edit your question to provide further information or clarification when necessary.

Answer (score 4):

A simple web search finds instructions from SWP's developers. These are untested as I have no access to SWP, but, if they don't work, you should contact them to ask for updated information.

Ref.: http://www.sciword.co.uk/mailings/May2016.htm

> 3. **TikZ:**    This Scientific WorkPlace v5.5 question started with an academic who's been on our mailing list since 2002 Emailing to say:
>
>    > I hope you don’t mind me asking a quick question.
>    >     I hoped that when I include the text below as an encapsulated TeX file in my SWP file that it would produce a figure for me. Instead it
>    >     is giving me error messages. Is there any quick fix for this? What is
>    >     the general advice if I want to include TeX (or otherwise) produced
>    >     mathematical figures?
>
>    and including the code for a TikZ picture. In our replies we said:
>
>    > If you want to include tikz pictures... you will need the tikz-cd package which is available at https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd.
>    >     
>    >     Have you added the tikz-cd package to your document (Typeset – Options & Packages – Package Options)? Because tikz-cd is not supplied
>    >     with Scientific WorkPlace, you will need to GoNative to add it.
>
>    You also need to ensure that the tikz package is available on your
>      computer, together with the packages it requires (xkeyval, pgf and
>      everyshi). You can obtain any further packages you require from CTAN,
>      but we have put the zip files you'll need here: tikz-cd, xkeyval, pgf
>      and everyshi (right-click – SaveAs). Simply unzip these files, and
>      save the folders they contain as
>      `C:\sw[p]55\TCITeX\TeX\LaTeX\contrib\tikz-cd\` etc; you should first
>      delete the old version of PGF in the folder
>      `C:\sw[p]55\TCITeX\TeX\LaTeX\contrib\pgf`. The sample `.tex` file here
>      will then compile to produce this PDF. You can put the TikZ TeX field
>      in a Display for centering and better spacing.
>
>    The instructions above are for v5.5. For v6.0, the only package you
>      need to add is tikz-cd; the sample `.sci` file here will then compile to
>      produce this PDF (intentionally showing a different graphic). When you
>      add the TeX Field in v6.0, the dialog asks you which packages it
>      requires; in this case, simply enter tikz-cd. You also need to make
>      sure that tikz-cd is available on your TeX Live installation (see Item
>      4 below).
>
>    Once you get our sample `.tex` or `.sci` files working, why not try with
>      your own TikZ graphics, or code obtained online? There are lots of fun
>      examples available at http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/ – though
>      you'll need to remember than anything before the `\begin{document}`
>      probably needs to go into the Preamble!
> 4. **Adding TeXLive packages (v6.0):**    Following on from Item 3 above, let's add the package tikz-cd as an example:
>
>    **Windows – TeX Live Manager** (instructions copied from our December 2015 mailing Item 4):
>
>    1. Double click the executable file tlmgr-gui.exe in the `c:\TeXLive\2015\bin\win32` folder    or 2016 (or later)
>    2. Click the "Load default" button and wait
>    3. Scroll through the list of Package names, locate whichever package is to be added and check the box (here adding the subfigure
>         package)
>    4. Click the "Install" button
>
>    You might need to update the TexLive Manager first.
>
>    **Mac – TeX Live Utility:**
>
>    1. Use the Finder to navigate to `/Applications/MacKichan/local/bin/TeXLiveUtility`
>    2. Click to open, and then click on Updates to see if any need installing
>    3. Click on Packages, and scroll down to tikz-cd (or enter it in the Search box).
>    4. Select the packages you wish to install using Cmd – Click (in our example, just tikz-cd)
>    5. Right-click and select Install Selected Packages
>    6. After a few seconds you will see the Install Succeeded message

Note that the suggestion to add the `subfigure` package is nonsense: this has been obsolete for ages. Use `subcaption` or, failing that, `subfig`. If SWP requires `subfigure` with a recent TeX installation, that's a bug on SWP's side and should be reported.